# Sql top x order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Can someone help me to understan why it does not work?

```
select top(10) * from
(select * from dbticket order by 1 desc ) a
```

the error is:

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

i have this ids in the 1st colum:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

i need to have the id is this way:

```
15
14
13
12
11..
```

Comment: Use that order by outside the derived table.

Comment: As per your error message your `Subquery uses ORDER BY without specifying TOP within the subquery itself`. What is the point of order by 1?

Comment: Look at the "unless"-part. So you could use `SELECT TOP(10) * FROM( SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM dbticket ORDER BY 1 DESC) a`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - you could, but that's just silencing the warning and potentially doesn't actually perform any sorting - and so you may as well say "you can remove the `ORDER BY` clause" - it'll have the same (guaranteed) effects.

Comment: If you can explain why you're not just using `select top(10) * from dbticket order by 1 desc`, we might be able to help out more

Comment: @Kaf `ORDER BY 1 DESC` is first column of the table

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
beacause in sql server it does fist the "top 10" and then the "order by" clause, but i need fist the "order by" and then the "top 10"

Comment: @RodolfoRollo - no, as I point to in a comment below one of the answers, `TOP` is processed after `ORDER BY`, for any given `SELECT` statement. The textual order of clauses in SQL is nothing like the actual (logical) processing order.

Comment: @RodolfoRollo check the update .. this might help you..

Comment: Got it `1` is a column name here.

Comment: @Deepshikha checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because of a fundamental T-SQL logic. T-SQL is a Set based theory and by SET we mean an `unordered` unique collection of objects. So `FROM` keyword works on `Sets` but when we add an `Order By` clause what we get is not a `set` any more it's what we can call a `CURSOR` or to be more specefic 'CURrent Set Of Rows'. 
So, that explains your question .. once you add `order by 1 desc` whatever data gets returned by `select * from dbticket` that is a `SET` gets transformed to `Cursor` which is uncompatible with `FROM Clause`.

Hope this helps!!

To get desired result write as:

```
;with CTE as 
(
select row_number() over (order by id desc) as rownum, --order by the first column ex: id
name, id --select * columns 
from dbticket)
select Top 10 name , id from CTE --give names of all the columns you need
order by rownum asc;
```

Check sample code [here.](http://rextester.com/YUQD39708)

Comment: It runs as i wanted, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbticket ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Subquery not required.

Comment: is this way sql server first do the "top 10" and then the "orde by" clause

Comment: @RodolfoRollo - see "Logical Processing Order of the [SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189499.aspx) statement". `ORDER BY` is step 10. `TOP` is step 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top(10) * from
(select * from dbticket order by 1 desc FOR XML AUTO) a
```

Comment: does not work: 
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'a'.

even if do:

select top(10) * from
(select * from dbticket order by id_ticket desc FOR XML AUTO) a

Comment: yeah basing on query i gave answer but we need to give column names

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from
(select top(10)  * from dbticket order by 1 desc ) a
```

Comment: What's the use of Outer sub query in your solution??

Comment: I believe entire scenario is not given jst required part is questioned this is solution provided to the question asked, may be you can use where condition or what ever it may be . But either if you use top 10 in inner or outer there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you have order by in you sub query must be use of Top option in select of your query. You can use `Top 100 Percent` in your query to get all rows from your sub query with order by option.

For example:

```
select top(10) * from
(select top 100 Percent * from dbticket order by 1 desc ) a
```

In your sample you can use following query :

```
select * from
(select top 10 * from dbticket order by 1 desc ) a
```

OR

```
select top 10 * from dbticket order by 1 desc
```